# Synthetic approach to hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: textbook-recommendation, books, hyperbolic-geometry

Hello,
I am looking for a source that discusses and teaches hyperbolic geometry from a synthetic approach (As opposed to the common analytinc approach in the poincare disk).  I am looking for something more in spirit with eucld's elements or hilbert's geometry book.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I'd say your best bet is with works from the early 20th century, when this sort of thing was in fashion:

- Julian Lowell Coolidge, [The elements of non-Euclidean geometry (1909)](http://archive.org/details/elementsofnoneuc00cooluoft)
- Horatio Scott Carslaw, [The elements of non-Euclidean plane geometry and trigonometry (1916)](http://archive.org/details/elementsofnoneuc00carsuoft)
- Duncan M'Laren Young Sommerville, [The elements of non-Euclidean geometry (1919)](http://archive.org/details/elementsofnoneuc00sommuoft)

Comment: I'll look into them all, but of those three, which would you recommend as the 'best'?

Comment: Depends for what. Carlslaw is the most illustrated and elementary, then Sommerville (which has exercises, and on p. 27 refers "the reader who wishes to study the development of non-euclidean geometry from a set of axioms" to Coolidge). Coolidge is more dry and more complete, with e.g. several chapters (IX, X, XVI) on line geometry in hyperbolic space: complexes, congruences, Malus-Dupin theorem, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Hartshorne's "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond" is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Download the article at [MARVIN](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=3729&pf=1) and look at the references.

Answer (score 0):

Cederberg's  A Course in Modern Geometries does some of this.